# How to find the display settings of asphalt 8 airborne pc version on my computer?

Tags: asphalt-8

I downloaded asphalt 8 PC version from Windows store and I don't know whether I am playing it on high, medium or low settings because when I go to settings > sound & display, I could not find any display settings. There's only camera and sound settings.

Can anyone tell me what's the default display settings and how could I change it? On mobile phone, I can see the display settings but not on my PC.

check this image - http://postimg.org/image/7271wfun9/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change display settings in asphalt 8 if you are running it on windows PC or Windows phone. But if you download asphalt 8 for Windows outside of store, u will be able to get that option.

Answer (score 0):

Update your game, you should see visual effects down below in the sound and display settings.